# What is a polite way to return a greeting like "Happy holidays and blah blah". A flat: "Likewise"?

Tags: politeness

When someone wish you good things like "Happy holidays and blah blah" Is a correct and polite way to answer a flat:

> "Thank you, likewise"

Or It should be better to respond:

> "Thank you, I wish you the same"

A teacher taught me the "likewise" one, but really I never have heard it in real greetings.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if I've ever heard anyone say "Likewise" in that exact context, but it certainly makes sense.  "I wish you the same" sounds a little stilted, but I think in a situation like this, the emotion is more important than the exact words.  If you want something informal, I think "Thanks!  And to you too!" is fine.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to say "Happy Holidays to you too!" back to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes down to personal preference, but it's quite common to echo the sentiment back to the person. For example.

> A: Happy Holidays!
>
> B: Thank you. Happy Holidays to you too!

It's also quite common to hear more informal responses, such as:

> - "And (also) to you!"
> - You too!
> - Thanks, same to you!
> - Happy New Year to you and yours (when you want to extend the wishes to the other person's family)

**"Many happy returns"** (although primarily used nowadays to mark a birthday), as also an acceptable response to *"Merry Christmas"* and "Happy New Year". The sentiment itself is issued the hope that a happy day being marked would recur many more times.

Comment: I think "many happy returns" may be regional. I'm certainly aware of it but not as something I ever hear anyone say in the modern era... for some reason I associate it more with British English.

Comment: @Catija: I wouldn't say that it's regional, but I'd certainly associate it with British English. And it's still in common usage, where I am from at least.

Comment: @catija: Ad multos annos is a classic everywhere people have some latin education. This mirrors it in english, doesn't it ?